# How to clear the screen in Win32 api

Tags: c++, api, winapi

I have a C++ windows API program which displays text using TextOut function

```
TCHAR buffer[] = _T("Hello");
        TCHAR buffer1[] = _T("How to clear this one\?");
        TextOut(hdc,200,170,buffer,_tcslen(buffer));
        TextOut(hdc, 200, 185, buffer1, _tcslen(buffer1));
```

My further text output has been overwritten like this[image]

how to clear the previous one and add this one.

I found that doing TextOut function on the same location like this

```
TextOut(hdc,200,170,buffer,_tcslen(buffer));
        TextOut(hdc, 200, 170, buffer1, _tcslen(buffer1));
```

will replace the previous one but for some other reasons I cannot do this
what is the actual way of clearing the screen.
Is there anything in windows like system("cls") for console 
Thank you

Comment: You are clearly painting incorrectly. The normal paint cycle will erase the background for you. You showed your code out of context. A [mcve] will let us tell you more.

Comment: Should I add more code?

Comment: Did you follow my link and read it carefully yet? Clearly the timing of your comment indicates you did not.

Comment: Sorry I did not know that was a link so why  asked a question.i'll read now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is improperly posed, as it seems that you think that the drawable surface of a window is somehow persistent - it isn't, the system is free to forget about all of its content and call your `WM_PAINT` handler to have it redrawn back to the state where it was. For this reason, the question feels strange: it's not that you erase some content that is already there (the window content is ephemeral), you arrange so that your paint code no longer paints what you don't want and force a repaint.

So, if you are doing your drawing in `WM_PAINT` like you should, you should set some kind of flag (or probably, clear the data structures that store the elements to draw) that tells your repaint code not to draw the text and do an `InvalidateRect(hwnd, TRUE)` to have your window background repainted and your `WM_PAINT` called.

My fear however is that you are not doing painting in `WM_PAINT` as you should, but scattered in other places using `GetDC` and the like (tip: in normal applications there's almost no place where you need `GetDC` or `CreateDC`); in this case, you are already doing it wrong (as you can see by minimizing and restoring your window), and you should [learn how to do it properly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd183315.aspx) before going on.

Comment: Related: [Difference between GetDC and BeginPaint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5841299/difference-between-getdc-and-beginpaint)